# Leader Election with Customization

Tags: distributed

I have multiple micro-service instances of same type. Each service instance will have connections to some of remote services. In below diagram, I have shown 3 service instance and 3 remote service. But In real field, It may have 3 service instances (or 5) and 1000 of remote resources. All service instances have capability to connect to any remote resource. Each remote resource should be connected to one ms instance as primary connection and one or more ms instance as secondary connection.

[image]

1. Any client request should be passed to service instance which has
   primary connection.
2. If service instance 1 goes down or losses connectivity to RR1 , then secondary connection in Service instance 3 should become primary connection. And new secondary connection should be created in 2nd service instance.
3. Primary role should be assigned based on some criteria (like latency between server and remote instance)

Questions

1. Please suggest some tools for my requirement.
2. Is there any sample implementation of custom leader election?

Comment: The first question "Is it possible to acheive this behavior with Zookeer" is off-topic here, so I remove it. But if you find out that Zookeeper is not usable for one reason or another, please edit your question to add that info, thanks!

Comment: Also, there are many typos in your question, I have fixed a few of them but please check.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. I rephrased my question.

Comment: Thanks! About (1): Asking "Does software X have feature Y" or "Is software X suitable for Y" is often frowned upon, please rephrase using advice from here: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/can-i-ask-if-a-particular-software-will-fit-my-needs I would recommend removing any mention of Zookeeper/Zuul/nginx/k8s from your question, to just concentrate on what your needs are. Then add a comment saying that you are wondering whether Zookeeper/Zuul/nginx/k8s would be suitable. Cheers!